# youtube iframe api Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of undefined

Tags: jquery, iframe, console, youtube-api

I have a video player that I am trying to implement here on the bottom right: http://downloads.raileurope.com/web_redesign/FinalFinal/redesign-michele/index.html

My problem is with the links underneath the video to navigate through videos (specifically clicking the dots). I used this technique http://jsfiddle.net/Y9j7R/5/ and it works fine in firefox and safari but not in chrome or ie. In the console I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'postMessage' of undefined. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The arrows work which is interesting because all i did there was mimic clicks on the dots (using next() and prev()) These don't work at all in ie7 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as though IE7 doesn't support HTML5 postMessage which is required for the youtube iframe api to work. Not sure why chrome bugs sometimes.

Comment: It is also now working in ie8 and 9. Nice but frustrating since it didn't work Friday and idk why.

Answer (score 0):

Your technique seem that works fine for me on Chrome (Version 19.0.1084.53 for mac). Don't printed " Cannot call method 'postMessage'" as you said

Comment: Interesting, what about ie? It is important for me to get it to work in ie because our client base is a lot of ie users.